# why any android office software can not play ppt properly

Tags: applications

I am having hard time to play ppt in android device, although many applications boasts for it, but on playing either they show blank slides or skip some parts ex:- title etc for some slide so any one know why this happen and how can I get rid of it ? Although I know easiest way is to make video from ppt and show on android device but for that we need acccess to pc.

Comment: Which apps are you using?  We can't answer "why" they don't perform properly, but we can help you with the "how" of getting something working.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Microsoft PowerPoint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.powerpoint&hl=en) for Android. It pretty much can do what its PC counterpart can.

Comment: But it requires android 4.4+

Comment: This is an answer.